# Know whether slider value was changed manually or programmatically in rangeslider.js?

Tags: rangeslider

I am using rangeslider.js

Here's my code:

```
$('#mySlider').rangeslider({
    polyfill: false,
    rangeClass: 'rangeslider',
    disabledClass: 'rangeslider--disabled',
    horizontalClass: 'rangeslider--horizontal',
    verticalClass: 'rangeslider--vertical',
    fillClass: 'rangeslider__fill',
    handleClass: 'rangeslider__handle',

    // on slide
    onSlide: function(position, value) { activateMyFunction(); },
});
```

I wanna perform actions inside activateMyFunction that depends on whether the range slider's value was changed programmatically or manually. By the way, i am using the following code to change the values programmatically: `$('#mySlider').val(myNewValue).change();`  Any solution?